# Bind selected option $index with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How can I bind selected option's **Index** using vue.js?
Code of select:

```
<select 
        v-model="address.districtId" 
        name="address[district_id]"
        id="address[district_id]"
        class="form-control"
    >
        <option value="0" selected disabled>
        Choose district
        </option>
        <option 
            v-for="district in places[cityIndex].districts" 
            value="@{{district.id}}"
        >
            @{{ district.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

I try to use

```
v-model:address.districtIndex="$index"
```

but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using `v-bind` (abbreviated as `:`) as shown below:

```
<select 
    v-model="selectedDistrictIndex" 
    name="address[district_id]"
    id="address[district_id]"
    class="form-control"
>
    <option value="0" selected disabled>
    Choose district
    </option>
    <option 
        v-for="district in places[cityIndex].districts" 
        :value="$index"
    >
        @{{ district.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

And use a computed to get the `districtId` like this:

```
computed: {
    selectedDistrictId: function () {
        return this.places[this.cityIndex].districts[this.selectedDistrictIndex].id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use **computed** with arrays? Beacuse I need array of address, each of them has own selected districtId

Comment: You should be able to return anything from a computed.